# Docker php-fpm 8.1 write permission denied

Tags: php, docker

On Manjaro linux, using the same Docker configs and php application, I have no issues with php being able to write to files. On my Manjaro box, when I `docker exec -ti my_php_container sh` and `ls -la` my php application files have permissions `1000:1000`.

However, on my Ubuntu 22.04 box, when building the docker container, and then examining the php application files in the container, their permissions are `root:root`. While the php application will load, all write functionality is permission denied. PHP `is_writable($path)` always returns false even with properly `chmod 775` directories. So, the culprit seems to be that Docker is not setting permissions correctly in the container.

My UID and GID are both 1000 on my Ubuntu box. Here is my current setup. I'm flummoxed, Docker typically just works, but on my new Ubuntu box permission is denied. Any thoughts on why the files in the container are not owned by 1000:1000 even though I'm creating this user and passing in the `user` data?

> Docker version 23.0.5.
> Note: I am able to run docker rootless, e.g. I can run `docker run hello-world` no problems. When I bring up this php application I do it without sudo and it comes up with zero errors. Both the Manjaro box and the Ubuntu box are using the same Docker version.

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.1.8-fpm-alpine
ARG UID
ARG GID
ENV UID=${UID}
ENV GID=${GID}

RUN addgroup -g ${GID} --system myname
RUN adduser -G myname --system -D -s /bin/sh -u ${UID} myname
```

#### www.conf

```
[www]
user = myname
group = myname
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 100
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 35
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
  php:
    container_name: my_php_container
    image: php:8.1.8-fpm
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./server/php-fpm
      args:
        - UID=${UID:-1000}
        - GID=${GID:-1000}
    user:
      "${UID:-1000}:${GID:-1000}"
    environment:
      XDEBUG_SESSION: docker
      CI_ENV: development
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
      - ./uploads:/var/www/uploads
```

Answer (score 1):

Wish there was a facepalm emoji I could put here. The one thing I did not do, when attempting to install docker without needing sudo, was to restart Ubuntu. I had only signed out and then signed back in. I hired a great devops guy on upwork to point out to me that I needed "turn it off and on again". Lol.

#### [From Docker install instructions:](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/)

```
# For fresh install remove anything old.
sudo apt remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
sudo apt update
sudo apt install \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg
sudo install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
echo \
  "deb [arch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)" signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  "$(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_CODENAME")" stable" | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
sudo apt update

# Install Docker CE
sudo apt install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin

# Run hello world with sudo. Should see hello world results without errors.
sudo docker run hello-world
```

#### [Post installation steps to run without sudo:](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER

# Register docker to start on boot.
sudo systemctl enable docker.service
sudo systemctl enable containerd.service
```

My critical error was that I assumed Ubuntu 22.04 would behave the same as Manjaro Linux. On Manjaro, signing out and back in registered my user as part  of the docker group. Ubuntu 22.04, on the other hand, needed a full restart before my user registered as part of the docker group. After the full restart, I could run docker without sudo and the permissions are once again correct in the container and I no longer have any write permission errors in my php app.

```
docker run hello-world
```

So "turn it off and on again" still applies in some parts of the Linux world. Ugh.

Comment: ‍♂️ here you go…

Comment: And there it is @Joe